# Why does "pip install lxml" not use the provided wheel, and tries to compile anyway?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, lxml, python-wheel

A [wheel](https://packaging.python.org/installing/#source-distributions-vs-wheels) is the new way of distributing pre-compiled packages for installation via pip.

The [lxml entry on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.6.4) has wheels available for "manylinux".  I am running ubuntu.

However, when I try to pip install lxml, it seems to try and compile anyway. Any ideas why?

```
mktmpenv
pip install lxml==3.6.4

Collecting lxml==3.6.4
  Using cached lxml-3.6.4.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lxml

  Complete output from command /home/harry/.virtualenvs/tmp-940224e01c89b3f0/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-gxw05tyo/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp78u4a871pip-wheel-:
  Building lxml version ....
  Building lxml version 3.6.4.
  Building without Cython.
  Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.29
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
[...etc]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: some modules use C/C++ code and authors decide to not compile it. You don't compile on your own - pip does it for you. I never had problem with compilation of lxml on Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: if you want precomiled lxml then use [Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs) - it installs Python and has precompiled lxml and other modules for this Python version.

Comment: thanks @furas, I can actually install the package just fine, my question is about why pip wants to compile even though a precompiled wheel is available.  have clarified my post.

Comment: What pip version do you have installed? What wheel version?

Comment: you have `Using cached lxml-3.6.4.tar.gz` so maybe try with `--no-cache-dir`

Comment: I've just tried this on Ubuntu 16.04 using pip 9.0.1 and couldn't reproduce the issue: the manylinux wheel was downloaded and installed directly. Just running `pip install lxml` did reproduce, but that's because there are not (yet) any wheels for this version.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks everyone!  So I think I found the answer.  There were actually two problems here, the first when I initially encountered the bug, and the second when I created the minimal repro (which I posted in the q).

- In the minimal repro, pip was finding a cached version of the *.tar.gz* of the sources, and was just using that instead of checking online for any wheels.  (HT  @oldmanuk and @furas for spotting that).   Aaaaaarguably this is a bug?  Anyway, lesson learned, my minimal repro wasn't.
- In the original problem, I was on Ubuntu **Trusty**.  I'm aware that older versions of pip don't do wheels well (cf @lukasa, @_rami_). I had anticipated that, and had a `pip install --upgrade pip` in my script.  What I didn't notice is that it was actually failing with the message `Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS` (as per [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2964)) and so I was still on pip 1.5.4, which was ignoring wheels.

So the ultimate fix was to manually force reinstallation of pip with

```
apt-get remove -y python-pip
wget -q https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py  # upgrade system pip to make sure we use wheels
```